# can I export an EBS snapshot and mount it to an on-prem server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, snapshot, rhel7

I have a scenario where data is being aggregated in an EBS-backed AWS EC2 instance and, periodically, that instance is shut down and snapshot. Ideally, the snapshot of that volume needs to be exported and mounted on an airgapped server.

Supposing I have RHEL 7 running in both environments, is there a way to export the snapshot of an EBS volume and mount it to an on-prem server? If not, is there a pattern for Cloud -> on-prem migration?

It looks like AWS' Snowball is bi-directional. I'm not sure how that works in practice. Can I take an EBS volume snapshot, export it to a device, ship that device, and mount it locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can export EBS volume to S3 bucket and download it. [Check this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html) for more info.

Check `~/.aws/credentials` for the profile name.

> To export your instance, use the create-instance-export-task command.
>   You must provide the information required to properly export the
>   instance to the selected virtualization format. The exported file is
>   saved in the S3 bucket that you specify.
>
> ```
> aws ec2 create-instance-export-task --region your-region --profile your-profile-name --instance-id id --target-environment target_environment \
> --export-to-s3-task DiskImageFormat=disk_image_format,ContainerFormat=ova,S3Bucket=bucket,S3Prefix=prefix
> ```